# Hot and cold water stopped flowing in shower at same time

Tags: plumbing

I heard a couple of kind of thuds sounds and then a few seconds later, all water flow stopped.  This lasted for several seconds (maybe a minute) and the all flow came back.  Water temp unchanged from what it was before flow stopped

Comment: What is your water supply? Municipal/utility (you have a water meter, no local supply) or well/cistern something with a local pump??

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a municipal/utility water supply I'd guess that a valve in the system was turned off, and then it (or another valve, if they were bypassing a section of pipe) was turned on.

If the problem recurs on a frequent basis, that may not be it. For a one-time or infrequent event, that's my best guess with this little detail to go on.

Comment: This is the first and only (so far) time this occurred.  Thank you for your explanation as we are on a city water supply.